# How can I get this do while loop to stop without "quit" causing a printout?

Tags: java, do-while

I've tried using this code, but everytime it runs and I type in quit, it prints out the result as if it should be a word and not a trigger to end the loop, then the loop ends. I tried just putting in an if then statement where if the word was quit it would end the entire program, but I can't get rid of the do while loop having the condition of word not equaling "quit". Here's the coding.

```
do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a word and I will see if, when the first letter is made the last" + '\n' + "and this word is spelled backwards, is the original word. Type quit to end: ");
            word = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
            
            String newWord = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0);
            String reverse = "";
        
            for(int wordLength = newWord.length() - 1; wordLength >= 0; wordLength--)
            {
                reverse = reverse + newWord.charAt(wordLength);
            }
        
            if (word.equals(reverse)) {
                System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? Yes!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? No");
            }
        }while (!word.equals("quit"));
```

As always, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The do while loop only checks the condition when it reaches the end of the loop. Therefore, what is happening in your code is, when word is set to "quit" the code below it still runs until it reaches the end of the loop.

To achieve what you want to do try this,

```
do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a word and I will see if, when the first letter is made the last" + '\n' + "and this word is spelled backwards, is the original word. Type quit to end: ");
            word = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

            if(word.equals("quit")){ break; }

            String newWord = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0);
            String reverse = "";
        
            for(int wordLength = newWord.length() - 1; wordLength >= 0; wordLength--)
            {
                reverse = reverse + newWord.charAt(wordLength);
            }
        
            if (word.equals(reverse)) {
                System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? Yes!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? No");
            }
        }while (true);
```

This will cause the for loop to stop before is outputs the text when quit is entered.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to replace your `else` statement with an `if else` checking for the word being `quit`, so the if-else part looks like this:

```java
if (word.equals(reverse)) {
    System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? Yes!");
} else if(!word.equals("quit")) {
    System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? No");
}
```

Comment: That coding pretty much caused the same thing to happen, it would tell that it doesn't make the same word, and it wouldn't end the program as well.

Comment: @KsProgrammer82 That is, because I forgot the `!` before the `word.equals("quit")`... Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change all of this with simple `while loop`. Like this:

```
   while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a word and I will see if, when the first letter is made the last" + '\n' + "and this word is spelled backwards, is the original word. Type quit to end: ");
        word = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (word.contentEquals("quit")) break;
        
        String newWord = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0);
        String reverse = "";
    
        for(int wordLength = newWord.length() - 1; wordLength >= 0; wordLength--)
        {
            reverse = reverse + newWord.charAt(wordLength);
        }
    
        if (word.equals(reverse)) {
            System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? Yes!\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have entered " + word + ". Does this word with it's first letter made the last then spelled in reverse become the original word? No\n");
        }
    }
```

This will run until the user enters "quit".

```
if (word.contentEquals("quit")) break;
```

This will break the loop and the program will stop.

Comment: Using `while(true)` loops is bad practice and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Why is that? while(true) or while(!word.equals("quit")) is not anything different from one another. While(true) allows your program to runs indefinitely which is the point of this program. It's just the readability of the code that can be an issue later and can cause trouble if the program runs into big changes. But this is a small few-line code sample that can use this and won't have any problems at all.

Comment: @MonsterDruide1 This situation is known as the "loop and a half" and has been studied by researchers; `while(true)` with a `break` halfway through avoids code duplication, and is easier for people to understand. It is also a very natural way of translating the programmer's intention into code, i.e. "keep reading input, but stop when they say 'quit'." Writing code this way should be encouraged.

Comment: @kaya3 I do agree that it may be easier to understand in this case, however when this loop grows and contains more than one exit condition, using a `break` to exit the loop may get very confusing when debugging the code within a bigger structure.  In contrast to using a condition within the loop: Here you can always see which action/input leads to an exit of the loop.

Comment: @MonsterDruide1 All of those things are best addressed by working at the appropriate level of abstraction. The code structure is "read an input, stop if an exit condition is satisfied, otherwise process it and repeat". If any or all of those steps becomes complicated then they can be factored out as other methods, and the code structure becomes like `while(true) { input = readInput(); if(exitCondition(input)) { break; } process(input); }`, any future changes to the code will only need to be made in other methods, and the loop itself always remains that short.

Comment: @MonsterDruide1 On the other hand, other ways of writing this code will naturally lead to code duplication because Java does not have any other control-flow structure intended for loops which logically should check their condition in the middle of the looped code. In the answer you've posted yourself, the condition `word.equals("quit")` is checked both in the `while` loop itself and also in an `else if` block inside the loop. Any future changes to the loop condition would need to be made in two places, and there is a likelihood that someone will cause a bug by only changing it in one place.